# If $(A − B) ∩ (A − C) = ∅$, then$ B ∩C = ∅ $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say whether the following sentence is true or not.
If $(A − B) ∩ (A − C) = ∅$, then $ B ∩C = ∅ $

If true, how to proof?, if false a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

$A=B=C=\{2\} \implies A-B=\emptyset \text{ and } A-C=\emptyset \implies (A-B)\cap(A-C)=\emptyset$.

But $B\cap C = \{2\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two disjoint sets $\tilde B$ and $\tilde C$.

Define $A:=\tilde B\sqcup\tilde C$.

Take a point $x\notin A$ and define $B:=\tilde B\sqcup\{x\}$ and $C:=\tilde C\sqcup\{x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\quad(A\smallsetminus B)\cap(A\smallsetminus C)=\emptyset~\iff~ A\subseteq(B\cup C)$

Also: $\quad B\cap C\subseteq B\cup C$.